# vb.net Invoke and Inheritance Design

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, dynamic, invoke

this is my first post here.

I like to have some advice on designing a new module for our software.
It's written in vb6 and i want to rewrite it in vb.net. So I want to refactor it.

It does the following:

We got many templates for OpenOffice Documents. (about 300)
Each one has an unique identifier which is in a database and comes as the input.

Dending on this number i want to create the document. e.g. calc or writer or later something else.
Then call a method named doc[template_num] or sth.

I read about invoking methods. I think this as a good way to dynamically call methods by number. Tried to do this. I think I understood now how it works.
But I dont know how to handle the document type. 
I want to reuse big parts of code due to all calc documents are created equal at the beginning. But filling the cells is just bit diffrent.

I dont know how to inherit and do method calls with invoke.

Maybe someone has a little code snip for me which can explain this to.
Or maybe some other good idea how to handle this problem.

I am thankful for any new thought on this.

Comment: Are the ID's for the templates always integers?  If they are, are they sequential, or are there gaps in the ID numbering sequence?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what you have tried so far?

Comment: yes. the ids are integers and sequential.

Answer (score 1):

You could, of course, just have a giant `Select Case` block, like this:

```
 Public Sub CreateDoc(templateNum As Integer)
     Select Case templateNum
         Case 1
             CreateDoc1()
         Case 2
             CreateDoc2()
         Case 3
             CreateDoc3()
     End Select
 End Sub
```

If you had a fairly small number of case statements that would probably be the better, simpler method.  If however, as you described, you have many different possible ID's to look for, then that becomes impractical and I can appreciate your desire to invoke the correct method without a big `Select Case` block.

However, before I get into that, I feel like I should give you another option.  Perhaps you don't really need to have that many different methods.  Is it possible, for instance, that half of the template ID's actually all need to be handled in the same way, and the only difference is the template file name that needs to be different.  If so, it is conceivable that the `Select Case` block wouldn't need to be that big.  For instance:

```
 Public Sub CreateDoc(templateNum As Integer)
     Select Case templateNum
         Case 1 To 100
             CreateWriterDoc(GetTemplateFilePath(templateNum))
         Case 101 To 200
             CreateCalcDoc(GetTemplateFilePath(templateNum))
     End Select
 End Sub

 Private Sub CreateWriterDoc(templateFilePath As String)
     ' Launch Writer with given template file
 End Sub

 Private Sub CreateCalcDoc(templateFilePath As String)
     ' Launch Calc with given template file
 End Sub

 Private Function GetTemplateFilePath(templateNum As Integer) As String
     ' Retrieve template file path for given ID 
     ' (from DB, Array, List, Dictionary, etc.) and return it
 End Sub
```

To me, that seems like a much simpler solution, if such a thing is possible.  If not--if you really have entirely different logic which needs to be executed for each template ID, then there are several ways to do it.  The first option would be to create a list of delegates which point to the appropriate method to call for each ID.  For instance, you could store them in an array, like this:

```
Dim createDocDelegates() As Action =
    {
        AddressOf CreateDoc1,
        AddressOf CreateDoc2,
        AddressOf CreateDoc3
    }
```

So now, those three delegates are indexed by number (0 through 2) in an array.  You can invoke them by number, like this:

```
createDocDelegates(1).Invoke()  ' Calls CreateDoc2
```

Or, if your ID's aren't sequential, you may want to use a `Dictionary(Of Integer, Action)`, instead, like this:

```
Dim createDocDelegates As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Action)()
createDocDelegates.Add(1, AddressOf CreateDoc1)
createDocDelegates.Add(7, AddressOf CreateDoc7)
createDocDelegates.Add(20, AddressOf CreateDoc20)
```

Then you can call one by ID, like this:

```
createDocDelegates(7).Invoke()  ' Calls CreateDoc7
```

Another option would be to create an `Interface` for an object that creates a document, like this:

```
Public Interface IDocCreator
    Sub CreateDoc()
End Interface
```

Then you could implement a separate class for each type of template (each implementing that same interface).  For instance:

```
Public Class Doc1Creator
    Implements IDocCreator
    Public Sub CreateDoc() Implements IDocCreator
        ' Do work
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Doc2Creator
    Implements IDocCreator
    Public Sub CreateDoc() Implements IDocCreator
        ' Do different work
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then, you can create a list of those objects, like this:

```
Dim docCreators() As IDocCreator = 
    {
        New DocCreator1(),
        New DocCreator2()
    }
```

Or:

```
Dim docCreators As New Dictionary(Of Integer, IDocCreator)()
docCreators.Add(1, New DocCreator1())
docCreators.Add(7, New DocCreator7())
docCreators.Add(20, New DocCreator7())
```

Then you can call one like this:

```
docCreators(1).CreateDoc()
```

The `IDocCreator` approach is very similar to the `Delegate` approach.  Neither is the right or wrong way to do it.  It depends on your style, what you are comfortable with, and your requirements.  The main advantage of the `IDocCreator` approach is that you could easily add more properties and methods to it in the future.  For instance, lets say that you also want to somewhere store a user-friendly, descriptive name for each template.  It would be very easy to add a `ReadOnly Property Name As String` property to the `IDocCreator` interface, but if you go the list-of-delegates route, that would be more difficult and sloppy.

In any of the above examples, however, you still have to add the complete list of methods or delegates somewhere.  So, while it's slightly less ugly than a giant `Select Case` block, it may still not be enough.  If so, the technology you need to use is called *Reflection*.  The `System.Reflection` namespace contains much of the reflection-related functionality.  Reflection allows you to dynamically access and invoke portions of your code.  For instance, you can use reflection to get a list of all of the properties or methods that are defined by a given class.  Or you can use reflection to get a list of types that are defined by your assembly.  Using reflection, it would be possible to get a method, by string name, and then invoke it.  So, for instance, if you want to call the `"CreateDoc1"` method on the current object, you could do it like this:

```
Me.GetType().GetMethod("CreateDoc1").Invoke(Me, {})
```

Since you are calling it by its string name, you could build the method name via concatenation:

```
Dim methodName As String = "CreateDoc" & templateNum.ToString()
Me.GetType().GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(Me, {})
```

However, if you are going to use the reflection approach, instead of using the name of the method, like that, it would be cleaner, in my opinion, to use a custom attribute to tag each method.  For instance, you could create an attribute class which allows you to decorate your methods like this:

```
<CreateDocMethod(1)>
Public Sub CreateDoc1()
    ' ...
End Sub
```

Then, at run-time, you can use reflection to find all of the methods that have that particular attribute and then invoke the right one.

The reason that I saved the discussion on reflection for last is because it is not as efficient and it can lead to brittle code.  As such, it's best to only use reflection as a last-resort.  There's nothing wrong with reflection, if you really need it, but, as a general rule, if there is another reasonable way to do something, which doesn't require reflection, then you probably ought to be doing it that other way.

Comment: I tried that reflection way and also did a little test with delegates.    It worked both for me but I thought reflection with invoking methods is a bit more dynamic because I dont have to store the name of the subs in a delegate array.   Didn't thought about effiency.    And by now it's handled with a giant select case block. and almost all of them are handled differently.

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help.  Yeah, only you know the specifics of your situation, so only you can pick the best solution :)  That's why I tried to cover all the ways I could think of.  Welcome to SO, by the way!  Hope to see you around in the future.